# Spring boot & mongo custom query with order by

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I have a custom query in `org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository` that goes

```
@Query("{'additionalInfo.suspicious' : true}")
List<Trip> findSuspiciousTripsByFleetId(String fleetId, Pageable pageable);
```

How could I add a order by (date desc) to this?

Does it magically accept `OrderByDateDesc` suffix for example?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this by adding a Sort attribute to the method. And pass the sort argument when calling the method.

```
@Query("{'additionalInfo.suspicious' : true}")
List<Trip> findSuspiciousTripsByFleetId(String fleetId, Sort sort);
```

And during invocation of this method, do

```
Sort sort = new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "date")
tripRepository.findSuspiciousTripsByFleetId("fleedtId", sort);
```

spring-data will take care of the rest for you.

Comment: not working for me Springboot + SpringData. using this line throws error ` query.with(new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC,"_id")); ' . import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;